# How to rename a json property only inside @JsonView?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I want to rename a `json` field, but *only* within a specific `@JsonView`.

Is that possible at all?

```
public class PersonDTO {
    @JsonView(View.Specific.class)
    private String personname;

    static class View {
          interface Specific {
               //@JsonProperty("firstname") //TODO this does not work
               private String personname;
          }
    }
}
```

If the view is not used, the fields name should just remain "personname".

Comment: Any update on this one ?